# No MaterialLocalizations found in flutter use GETX

Tags: flutter

when I tab on input to open datepicker dialog, it was error

[image: Please click to view image]

Please help me , I use GETX Flutter

This is main.dart

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GetStorage box = GetStorage();
    //print(box.read('lang'));
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      locale: LocalizationService.getLocaleFromLanguage(
          langCode: box.read('lang') ?? 'en'),
      fallbackLocale: LocalizationService.fallbackLocale,
      translations: LocalizationService(),
      initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
      getPages: AppPages.routes,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Provide necessary code to reproduce the issue, More about [minimal reprucible example stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please view my below answer

Comment: I've no idea about getx and you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73163854/edit), doesnt it happens without getx too? also provide code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: I'm not check without GetX yet

Comment: try with MaterialApp insplace of GetMaterialApp

Answer (score 2):

you have to add those attributes to `GetMaterialApp` widget:

```
    supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('ar'),
      // add other supported locals
    ],
    localizationsDelegates: const [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      // add other library integrated locals
    ],
```

don't forget to import :
`import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';`

in `pubspec.yaml`:
add if not exist: `intl: ^0.18.0` and add this:

```
 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this

```
GetMaterialApp(
      title: "Application",
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```

and dont forget import [pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdMMy.png)